# Why does the shell perform pathname expansion for utilities?

Tags: c, shell, unix, grep

This question is a sequel of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7136899/how-does-grep-work

It seems that the `shell` does the expansion of `*.*` to all applicable/available files and provide that to utilities like `grep`.

Why does the `shell` need to do that? Why not leave pathname expansion to the utility itself?

Comment: Why do hammer manufacturers screw the head to the handle? Why not leave that to the craftsman?

Comment: This is especially fun if you have a file named `-rf` and you use `rm`...

Comment: One thing that you should be aware of if you're coming from a Windows environment: the correct wildcard for "all non-hidden files in the current directory" is `*`, not `*.*`.  It's very common in Unix/Linux to have files with no dots in their names.  The system makes far less use of file extensions to decide what kind of file something is.  For example, you'll commonly see "README" rather than "README.TXT".

Comment: and in Windows the shell does not do the expansion the utility does. So allowing rename *.txt *.bak

Comment: @Mark: Thanks. Windows is really a beautiful piece of code :D

Comment: Hey now. VMS *is* a beautiful piece of code and it too leaves wildcard expansion to the invoked program. :) Of course, it provides a bunch of library routines that programs can use to do that, as well as providing default extensions, etc. - for example cc * won't compile every file, only the .c, etc., files.) A big advantage of this approach is that the command interpreter doesn't impose any maximum length on the resulting command. The program just gets the parameter as it was typed, and only has to fetch and deal with one resulting filename at a time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well one reason is that every utility would have to implement that functionality,.  If the shell does it, it's only implemented once.

Answer (score 2):

Because if the shell didn't provided this feature, every single small utility would have to implement it.

This also ensures that the expansion works exactly the same way for every command.

BTW the expansion does not occur only in command arguments, it can occur anywhere in a shell script; for example:

```
for file in *.c; do something; done
```

Comment: Not quite anywhere, though: in `case $foo in *) command;; esac` the * is syntactically a pattern, not a glob character for pathname expansion. Your shell man page or POSIX spec has all the gory details.

Answer (score 2):

If the shell didn't provide that functionality, then every utility would need to implement their own wildcard functionality (and probably most wouldn't bother doing so). As it is, each utility only has to process individual file names, which is much simpler.

Answer (score 1):

Because life would be nightmarishly horrible if it didn't.

Comment: Ok, I admit this isn't terribly constructive.

Answer (score 1):

It's the Unix philosophy of "Have one tool do one thing well".
Why would anybody want that code repetition in every utility? What's the point of having each and every utility after main() call expand_pathnames()? What's the point of putting that burden not only on C programs, but on all compiled languages and script languages as well? There is no point in all of that. Which is why Microsoft and the cmd.exe abomination got it wrong from day one :-)

BTW, if you want to turn off file name globbing, you can do that with

```
$ set -f
$ echo *
*
$ set +f
$ echo *
readme foo.o bar.txt
```